# Error propagation in a linear model

Tags: model, error, linear, uncertainty, error-propagation

I am currently interested in learning more on error propagation. At the moment I am trying to find out how to calculate the uncertainty of a value that is obtained from a linear model. For the linear model, the uncertainty of the slope and of the intercept with the x-axis are given. I have not found any useful explanation or I did not recognize one, because they were too complex for me.
The Model would be:

```
y = s * (x-X0)
```

where:

```
s=slope (=0.9)
x=value on the x-axis (=25)
X0=intercept with the x-axis (= 5)
```

I want to know *dy*, the uncertainty of y.
I know that:

```
ds = uncertainty of s (= 0.01)
dx = uncertainty of the actual x-value (= 2)
dX0 = uncertainty of the intercept with the x-axis (= 1.5)
```

This appears to me as a simple problem, so it should not necessary to solve the model with all possible values s, x and X0 could have. Or am I wrong here?
I also appreciate recommendations on text-books, if you have any.
Kind regards,
S.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you are correct.

For other readers, there are a number of clear summaries of how to propagate errors through a linear system.

Here are three of the best ones I found:

1. http://ipl.physics.harvard.edu/wp-uploads/2013/03/PS3_Error_Propagation_sp13.pdf
2. http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/mpc/section5/mpc552.htm
3. http://lben.epfl.ch/files/content/sites/lben/files/users/179705/Error%20Propagation_2012.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I eventually figured it out by myself: The possible errors of the components have to be propagated separately and then summed up:

```
model error=slope error+value error+intercept error
```

This looks like this:

```
dy = (ds*(x-X0)) + (s*dx) + (s*dX0)
```

So this would yield for my example:

```
dy=(0.01*(25-5)) + (0.9*2) + (0.9*1.5)
```

thus:

```
dy=3.35
```

This is consistent with the value I would obtain when solving the linear model with all possible combinations of values (results range between 16.333 and 19.684).